# PWA Scope still showing in undesired routes

Tags: angular, progressive-web-apps, service-worker, manifest, angular-pwa

I Havea angular project v16 and i want to make a PWA but only on the private section (all routes start with 'pagex/tt') already setted the "scope": "/pagex/tt/" in the manifest file but is still showing the install prompt qnd toolbar icon on the root ("/")

Tried different approaches
Changing the scope to "/pagex/"